# There is a way to make an object A behave like an object B?

Tags: java, android, json

I have two objects A and B:

```
    public class A {
      @SerializedName("idProject")
      private int id;

      @SerializedName("nameProject")
      private String name;

      //with setter and getters and other methods
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////

    public class B {
      @SerializedName("idMenu")
      private int id;

      @SerializedName("nameMenu")
      private String name;

      //with setter and getters and other methods
    }
```

These objects are filled from a json, which comes from a service. I have no problems to consume the service.
But in another part of my code, I have a method that requires an object like this:

```
    public void method(C c){
      ....
    }


    public class C {
      private int id;

      private String name;

      //with setter and getters and other methods
    }
```

How can I pass an object A or B to this method that accepts only objects of type C ?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, you want a type casting behavior here. Since you can't cast object A or B to C in Java, you will have to implement methods in A and B that give you the equivalent C object.

```java
class A {
    //...
    C C() {
        return new C(id, name);
    }
}

class B {
    //...
    C C() {
        return new C(id, name);
    }
}

class C {
    //...
    C(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Now you can easily call `C()` method to get the equivalent `class C` instance and pass it to the specified method.

```java
method(objA.C());
```